# How should I connect my new light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I’m trying to install a bathroom light fixture. It has one white, one black, and one copper wire

I opened the wall and I have 2 black 2white 2 copper and one red. I can get the light to come on but not to work off of the light switch. Help please

Comment: I would recommend you search the site, this question has been answered many many times. We will also need to know what was there before (if you know) and how many switches, what did they control, etc.Also, do you have a meter? A Hot wire tester? You said "wall" vs. "Ceiling" is this above a vanity?

Comment: what does this mean? `I can get the light to come on but not to work off of the light switch`

Comment: I think he means he has found a way to connect the light such that it is always on but not such that the nearby switch turns it on and off.

Comment: Open up that switch, don't take any wires apart, take a good picture showing what color wire is connected where on the switch, show how the wires enter the box (how many and which direction the come from up/down) and edit that into your question.   (When you took the old one down, you took too much apart, you should have left most of it connected the way it was and just disconnected the wires that actually connected to the old fixture.)